# Bootstrap - list-group to take entire width of the div

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a div which is 200px in height. How do I divide the ul items in equal rows? They always align on top. I have colored the div green to make it obvious. Eventually I would be using ngFor in my ul, so I do not know how many rows are going to be there

```
<div style="height:200px">
   <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
     <li class="list-group-item border-0 bg-transparent ">
        test
     </li>
     <li class="list-group-item border-0 bg-transparent">
        test1
     </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: as you know the exact height of div then why don't you give 100px height to child element also...

Comment: instead of using hard coded height use grid of bootstrap https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/grid/

Comment: I would be using ngFor in my ul, so I do not know how many rows are going to be there

Comment: in given solution you can add ngFor in tr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to divide the content of your div then its best you should use table

```html
<table style="height: 200px;">
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let hero of heroes">
      <td class="align-baseline">
           <td>{{hero.name}}</td>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

This is another way by which can give height to li

```html
<ul  class="list-group list-group-flush" style="line-height:180%">
    <li class="list-group-item border-0 bg-transparent ">
        test
     </li>
     <li class="list-group-item border-0 bg-transparent">
        test1
     </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Could you please explain why 180%?

Comment: line-height specifies the height of line, it have different types of value % is one of it.

Comment: more details of line-height is here https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_line-height.asp

Answer (score 0):

Would a flexbox solution work for you?
https://codepen.io/panchroma/pen/ExWpdeK

HTML

```
<div class="wrap">
  <ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.wrap ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
  height: 200px;
}  
.wrap {
  background-color: green;
}
```